# How to specify the arguments of a multi-variable function when using multiprocessing Pool in python?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to find some of the solutions of the Pythagorean relation using multiprocessing module in python in the following snippet. To speed up the process of finding the answers, I am trying to parallelize the process:

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array
import numpy as np

MAXIMUM_INT: int = 10
answers = {'A': [], 'B': [], 'C': []}

base_range = np.arange(1, MAXIMUM_INT + 1)

A_range = B_range = C_range = base_range.tolist()

combinatorics = [A_range, B_range, C_range]
iteration = list(itertools.product(*combinatorics))

dim1 = dim2 = dim3 = MAXIMUM_INT


def init(A: int, B: int, C: int):
    global test1, test2, test3
    test1, test2, test3 = A, B, C


def conditionalAssert(answerDict: dict, A: int, B: int, C: int):
    t1 = np.frombuffer(test1.get_obj())
    t2 = np.frombuffer(test2.get_obj())
    t3 = np.frombuffer(test3.get_obj())

    if A**2 + B**2 == C**2:
        answerDict['A'].append(t1)
        answerDict['B'].append(t2)
        answerDict['C'].append(t3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    relevantArray = Array('i', dim1 * dim2 * dim3)
    A = B = C = relevantArray
    pool = Pool(processes=7, initializer=init, initargs=(A, B, C))
    pool.starmap(conditionalAssert, iteration)
    print(answers)
```

However, running the script "as is" creates an error that I don't know how to solve. I would appreciate any help:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 51, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: conditionalAssert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'C'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\pythagorean.py", line 38, in <module>
    pool.starmap(conditionalAssert, iteration)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 375, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 774, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: conditionalAssert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'C'
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? I'm seeing that you're doing `A**2 + B**2 == C**2`, i'm not sure if `multiprocessing` is the right approach here.

Comment: This is just a MWE for something else I am trying to solve. I know it's not the right choice but I am trying to experiment with multiprocessing.

Comment: `iteration` generates tuple of 3 elements, but your function `conditionalAssert` expect 4 parameters. Thus you get the error that the last parameter `C` is missing.

Comment: I realized that but I couldn't find a solution to resolve that issue.

Comment: You could remove `answerDict: dict` from the parameter list and instead `conditionalAssert` should return an object. In the `__name__ == '__main__'` you get all these objects from `.starmap` and construct the final one. Another approach is using https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Comment: So, how can I print the updated version of the dict after this line: pool.starmap(conditionalAssert, iteration)?

Comment: you can do `for object_returned_from_conditionalAssert in pool.starmap(conditionalAssert, iteration): <update the dict with this object>`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on <update the dict with this object> with a solution to my question?

Comment: If you return from the `conditionalAssert` tuple of three elements `(e1, e2, e3)` then the update could look `answers['A'].append(e1);answers['B'].append(e2);answers['C'].append(e3)`

Comment: But conditionalAssert already does that in the process. I just need to print the final version of the dict {A: [3,...], B: [4,...], C:[5,....]}

Comment: Every process has it's own memory, so it's updating it's own copy of dict. You have to return the object to main process somehow or use shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestions from Andrej Kesely, I was able to modify my original script to account for the issues that were raised as part of my initial draft. Here is my solution to the problem. (Again, thank you! and please let me know if it can be done better):

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array, RawArray
import numpy as np

MAXIMUM_INT: int = 10
answers = {'A': [], 'B': [], 'C': []}

base_range = np.arange(1, MAXIMUM_INT + 1)

A_range = B_range = C_range = base_range.tolist()

combinatorics = [A_range, B_range, C_range]
iteration = list(itertools.product(*combinatorics))

dim1 = dim2 = dim3 = MAXIMUM_INT

def init(A: int, B: int, C: int):
    global test1, test2, test3
    test1, test2, test3 = A, B, C


def conditionalAssert(A: int, B: int, C: int):
    test1 = RawArray("i", dim1)
    test2 = RawArray("i", dim2)
    test3 = RawArray("i", dim3)

    t1 = np.frombuffer(test1, dtype=int)
    t2 = np.frombuffer(test2, dtype=int)
    t3 = np.frombuffer(test3, dtype=int)

    if int(A**2 + B**2) == int(C**2):
        answers['A'].append(A)
        answers['B'].append(B)
        answers['C'].append(C)
        return A, B, C
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    relevantArray = Array('i', dim1 * dim2 * dim3)
    A = B = C = relevantArray
    pool = Pool(processes=7, initializer=init, initargs=(A, B, C))
    for object_returned_from_conditionalAssert in pool.starmap(conditionalAssert, iteration):
        if object_returned_from_conditionalAssert:
            e1, e2, e3 = object_returned_from_conditionalAssert
            answers['A'].append(e1)
            answers['B'].append(e2)
            answers['C'].append(e3)

    print(answers)
```